# ImportError: cannot import name 'Settings' from 'settings'

Tags: python, class, module, runtime-error

This is the content of Alien_invasion.py:

```
import pygame
import sys

#here im importing the class from the settings class
from settings import Settings


def run_game():

 
    ai_settings = Settings()


    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")


    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)


    while True:
        ...

run_game()
```

This is within the settings.py:

```
class Settings():

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

When trying to run Alien_invasion.py, the following error occurs:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Settings' from 'settings'`

Comment: Are you sure both files are in the same directory? I cannot reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try import settings and ai_settings = settings.Settings(). Also, make sure the two files are in the same folder.